# sveltkit and firebase, srr vs no ssr

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, server-side-rendering, sveltekit

I want to build a sveltekit application that uses firebase and firebase auth. I want to deploy it with the new firebase hosting option for sveltekit. But I dont want to handle the auth server side and only a small part of my app needs user data. I want to render everything serverside and the pages with auth only client side.

Problems:

1. I have a global layout that acts as a nav bar with Icon if the user is logged in or not. Is does this need to be server side rendered fore the rest to be server side rendered? Is it even a problem when its server side rendered, because as soon as client side rendering takes over it should be correctly displayed?
2. I want to restrict the login routes with route groups and if not authenticated then redirect to the login page. This would off course only run client side. Would this work?

But the main question for me is does this approach makes sense or should I just render the whole app server side?